# Git Pull not showing changes

Tags: github

I have created a branch web_developer1 on my local . When i click on 'Create New Pull Request' on the Git Web UI , it says both **There isn’t anything to compare.** and **Both the branches are identical**  when i compare the **master** branch and the branch named **web_developer1**

But when i type the command

```
git status
```

It shows that i have a file that has been changed and needs to be committed .

Any advice would be helpful as i am pretty new with Git .

Answer (score 0):

Normally a pull request is raised/created *after* you have committed and pushed your changes.

Have you tried

```
git add $yourFile
git commit -m "your message"
git push
```

then try the create pull request on you web GUI